# Lumen for both webservice and website

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have to develop a web service and a admin panel. Initially I thought of developing **web service in Lumen** and **Admin panel in Laravel**. If I go like this I have to repeat the code base for basic entities like User, Categories, Products etc. So my question is Can I use Lumen for both?.

- Admin side: Lumen + Angular/Some other
- Webservice: Lumen

I researched and found that in Lumen, some packages are not included for maintaining the speed. If required, is it possible to add this packages later?

Please advice me.

Comment: So Kiren, what did you do? could you give me a direction as well?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj 
You don't need to mix admin and service together. When app grows, it will be very painful for maintanance.
For admin you can stick with Laravel and for services use Lumen. While using Lumen try to avoid Eloquent for queries instead use raw db queries to increase the performance. If you are expert in front technology like Angular and ViewJs you can use Lumen for admin too. Other wise it will increase your learning curve.

Comment: Thanks Kiren, I was also thinking of going for Angular and use Lumen so that same code can be used. If it may really become a problem in future, I think then I need to go for Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to give this article a look [Building an API for your Laravel Application with Lumen](http://blog.enge.me/post/building-api-your-laravel-application-lumen) its a bit old and Lumen has changed a lot lately but the principle should still apply. Create your Laravel app and using a git submodule include it as a dependency on your Lumen project. This lets you reuse some of your code such a models with ease.

The two key bits are include your Laravel project as a submodule

`git submodule add --force git@github.com:adamgoose/laravel laravel`

update your Lumen `composer.json` to autoload your Laravel code as well

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Application\\": "laravel/app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The link is dead, can you provide the updated one?